# NoMethodError in Home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rotas

Seguinte, recebi um desafio de criar uma pagina com login, usando devise e com o user logado, que ele pudesse criar uma lista de tarefas, um to-do list.

O login eu consegui fazer e funciona bem, já criar a parte dos posts esta sendo o maior problema. criei alguns arquivos, o model, o controler, uma partial e a view que deve chamar essa partial.

O erro insistente é:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
2: <%= form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
3:     <% if @todo_list.errors.any? %>
4:         <div id="error_explanation">
5:           <h2><%= pluralize(@todo_list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this todo_list from being saved:</h2>
```

Eu já debuguei, o @todo_list vem nulo, não sei o porque, já que aparentemente  tudo esta bem declarado e instanciado.

Eis o model:

`class ToDoList < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :is_favorite, :name, :description
  has_many :tasks,  dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :member
end`

o controller:

```
`class ToDoListsController < ApplicationController

  def index
...
  def show
...
  end

  def new

        @todo_list = ToDoList.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @todo_list }
     end`
```

o trecho da view que chama a partial:

```
<% if member_signed_in? %>

    <%= render partial: 'to_do_lists/to_do_list' %>
    <%= link_to "Saída", destroy_member_session_path, :method => :delete %>

<% else %>
```

as rotas:

```
new_member_session GET    /members/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            member_session POST   /members/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_member_session DELETE /members/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           member_password POST   /members/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_member_password GET    /members/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_member_password GET    /members/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                           PUT    /members/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_member_registration GET    /members/cancel(.:format)        registration#cancel
       member_registration POST   /members(.:format)               registration#create
   new_member_registration GET    /members/sign_up(.:format)       registration#new
  edit_member_registration GET    /members/edit(.:format)          registration#edit
                           PUT    /members(.:format)               registration#update
                           DELETE /members(.:format)               registration#destroy
                 dashboard        /dashboard(.:format)             home#dashboard
                  register        /register(.:format)              registration#register
                      root        /                                home#index
```

**Edit:**
Uma coisa deu certo, mas não é o ideial...

```
<%= form_for(@todo_list = ToDoList.new) do |f| %> 
<%#= form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
    <% if @todo_list.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@todo_list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this todo_list from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @todo_list.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

Trocar o @todo_list para TodoList.new. Funcionou, mas não da pra eu fazer isso toda hora ;/.

### Edit2

Função index:

```
class ToDoListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todo_lists = ToDoList.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @todo_lists }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Qual o conteúdo do método index da classe ToDoListController?

Comment: Como bem disse o @Bernardo, o erro é na ação `index` e você só postou o código de `new`

Comment: desculpa galera, o codigo:

`class ToDoListsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @todo_lists = ToDoList.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @todo_lists }
    end
  end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A seguinte sintaxe:

```
<%= form_for @modelo do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Só funciona se `@modelo` for uma instância de `ActiveRecord::Base`.

No seu caso você fez isso:

```
@todo_lists = ToDoList.all
```

Isso significa que `@todo_list` é uma instância de `ActiveRecord::Relation`, o que significa que ele é ***uma lista*** de objetos desse modelo, e não ***um modelo*** apenas.

Quando você usou `@todo_list = ToDoList.new` ele passou a funcionar porque agora sim você tem apenas um modelo.

Normalmente se faz assim:

```
def index
  @modelos = Modelo.all
end

def new
  @modelo = Modelo.new
end
```

E criamos em `new.html.erb` o formulário de cadastro e em `index.html.erb` apresentamos todos os modelos (dentro de uma `<table>`, por exemplo).

Comment: Sim, eu passei a fazer o new e o index para funcionar e  abandonei a ideia do partial que eu tinha. Me disseram para tentar usar partials quando eu estiver mais firme. Mas como eu poderei ter o login já pronto e a to-do list na mesma página se eu não consigo usar partial?

Comment: @Amancio Você quer ter a lista toda e ainda o formulário na mesma página? Você pode instanciar as duas variáveis na mesma ação/método: `@modelo = Modelo.new` e `@modelos = Modelo.all`. Use `@modelos` para exibir a lista e `@modelo` para o formulário.

Comment: Sim. a ideia é logar, parecer o form da criação da lista, o que já foi criado e um botão de sair para deslogar. Então eu crio meu @modelo no controller "modelo_controller" mesmo e depois só chamo para outro controller?

Comment: A página de login teria que ser na mesma página? Pra mim faz sentido que você tenha duas página, uma de login (página e controlador do próprio Devise, normalmente) e outra com a lista e o formulário (todo_list_controller). Não entendi o que você quis dizer com "outro controller", o formulário e a lista estarão no `index` e o formulário vai apontar para `create` que depois redireciona de volta para o `index`.

Comment: Eu tenho três controllers. Um do Devise, Um chamado home e o outro do to_do_lists. Hm, acho que entendi onde me atrapalhei. Não tinha a necessidade de eu criar  um controller a mais para to_do_list se tinha o da home, que é onde a lista e o form devem estar. Fora que após logado o user já é jogado para home. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: @Amancio De nada, é bom poder ajudar. Bom fim de semana! =)